# In C++. whats the difference between (*a).b and a->b?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax

I am learning C++ in a advanced programming class from my work since I have only worked in Web and .NET languages so far.
In a midway test the instructor has marked all of my uses of (*a).b as wrong and deducted points for it, which could negatively affect my final score and I need a near perfect score to transision in work from web stack to application stack, so could some of you help me resolve this dispute?

Comment: Please provide an example and be as specific as possible.

Comment: They are equivalent; The "->" is just syntactic sugar

Comment: They are equivalent, but the arrow is less of an ugly kludge when you have it as part of a more complicated expression. Which is probably why your instructor doesn't want you to do `(*a).b`. In the end, code quality doesn't only include that the code does what it is supposed to do, but also that it is maintainable and can be easily understood.

Comment: Obviously, (*a).b is correct in (almost, see Quentin's answer) all cases, so you could argue that the point deduction wasn't justified. In reality, I prefer a->b  because it's more concise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `a` is a pointer, there's no difference in functionality at all, and in fact one is expressed in terms of the other [[expr.ref§2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2.sentence-3)]:

> The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`; the remainder of [expr.ref] will address only the first option (dot).

If `a` is an instance of a class with overloaded operators `*` and `->`, there *could* be a difference. But such a discrepancy would be surprising, and I'd consider the *class* to have a bug because of this.

In the end, it's all about convention and readability then. The `->` operator exists as a shorthand for the `*`/`.` pair, as it is shorter and has better precedence rules (no need for parentheses). Thus, one would indeed use it rather than `*`/`.`.

Comment: `unique_ptr` with custom deleter may have different behaviour too  , `*` always gives reference to the stored type but `->` may give a custom class

Comment: @M.M that's... bizarre.

Comment: @M.M no mention of that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*)

Comment: @AlanBirtles look at the return type of `operator->`